# VB.Net 2015 "Disable btn_MouseLeave on btn_MouseClick"

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

In VS 2015 Community, My form as a button.

Current Code is:

```
Private Sub CellStart_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CellStart.MouseHover

    CellStart.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.graycell_hilight

End Sub

Private Sub CellStart_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CellStart.MouseLeave

    CellStart.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.graycell

End Sub

Private Sub CellStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CellStart.Click

    CellStart.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.graycell_select

End Sub
```

What I want is that if the button is in the post click state (Current BackgroundImage is graycell_select), for the MouseLeave and Mouse Hover to no longer be enabled. If the button becomes deselected I need them to be enabled again. I have tried if statements, assigning an integer +1 on click but nothing seems to override the leave and hover events. I am dreadfully new so any help or points to something similar is appreciated. Thanks in advance. This is in a winform.

Comment: Utilize the [**GotFocus**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus(v=vs.110).aspx) and [**LostFocus**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus(v=vs.110).aspx) events.

Answer (score 0):

Click your button and Find the `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` in the Event tab.

Click `GotFocus` and put this code inside of it.

`CellStart.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.graycell_hilight`

Click `LostFocus` and put this code inside of it.

`CellStart.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.graycell`

leave the `click` on what it has.

Dont forget to remove not just copy remove the codes in the `MouseHover` and `MouseLeave`